# iOS ssl certificate validation - Cannot verify server identity

Tags: iphone, ssl-certificate

If I use safari on iOS device to access a particular URL (https) where the server has an invalid certificate, safari gives me the alert saying "Cannot verify server identity". Means Safari has implemented certificate validation.

But on my iPhone app when I use NSURLCOnnection with the same URL(https), how can I validate certificate whether it is expired, self-signed or untrusted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at NSURLConnectionDelegate's `connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge`